# how to make an image use the full width of the screen in Joomla

Tags: css, joomla

I am to looking to find out how i can add image that will take up the full width of the screen.

I have currently downloaded the new version of Joomla 3.7.4 and have duplicated the Protostar Template to try and do this.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

Comment: Go into the template and add `width: 100vw` to the relevant selector.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to use the whole width of the content area? If so you can do this with plain CSS. Just add `style="width: 100%"` to the image tag like `<img src="" style="width: 100%;">`. A better way would be to add a new style to the templates CSS file.

I usually upload images larger than the maximum size and have a general CSS rule for images `img {max-width: 100%}`. Images will be scaled down to fit the width of the content area so I don't need to add additional style information to each image.

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses, I was looking for some examples of sites that have what I am trying to build and came across http://www.furnesspartnership.com/ which has the image across the whole screen...